# Can I preload content in a Webbrowser control?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, webbrowser-control, preload

I have a VC++ MFC dialog application with a web browser ActiveX control. I have "Next" and "Prev" buttons using which I let the user navigate through a list of pre-defined URLs, whose content are shown in the web browser control. Since I know the list of URLs at the start itself, I would like to pre-load the content in some way while the user is looking at one page, so that when they click on "Next", the content has already been fetched and can be shown to the user instead of waiting for the page to load. I did not find any documentation on how to do that so far. Does anyone have any ideas on how to achieve this? I was thinking of having a second invisible web browser control where I pre-load the next URL, but it would be tricky to handle the user clicking Next when the next URL is still loading in the other browser.

Comment: Why would that be a problem if two browsers happen to navigate to the same URL at the same time? Why would that situation need to be "handled" in any special way?

Comment: On the user's clicking Next I would need to show the text in the visible browser, so I would need to do something like copy the text from the invisible browser to the visible one. But if the invisible browser is only partially loaded with the content at that point, I would get partial content in the visible browser as well. How would I continue to load the rest of the content in the visible browser?

Comment: I thought the point of the invisible browser would just be to prime the cache, so that, when visible browser goes to the same URL later, most of the content happens to be cached locally. In this scenario, the worst that could happen is that the content is not in fact in the cache and the browser needs to fetch it from the server. I'm not sure how you planned to go about "copying the text".